# I want to create a C++ program to generate random numbers into a file

Tags: c++

I'm making a C++ program to generate a million random numbers (I've generated them as just cout output once so I have the processing power) and I want to write them into a file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int value;
    ofstream file ("numbers.txt");
    file.open ("numbers.txt", ios::out | ios::app );
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 1000000)
    {
        value = rand(); 
        file << value;
    }
    file.close();
    
}
```

This is my current code, and I get no errors, but when I run it I see an empty txt file in my file explorer.
Can anyone tell me what's the problem here?

I tried it for only 100 numbers, and I got a blank text file

Comment: Not sure why you are attempting to open the file 2 times.

Comment: `i` appears to be invariant. How does your loop terminate?

Comment: Probably `file.flush()` before closing to dump the data in file

Comment: You might want to increment your loop variable.

Comment: ***Also, the command prompt that opens when I run the exe never closes.*** The reason is your loop never ends because you never increase the value of `i`

Comment: Use `++i;` or add a semicolon to the statement you added. Then try `while (i < 100)` to see that your code does produce numbers. You could also use an IDE like Visual Studio to debug your  code. I had the code working for 100 numbers in less than a minute  in Visual Studio.

Comment: @leaves Please don't edit the code after you get answers, as it makes the answers meaningless. At the very least make it clear that you have editted the code.

Comment: I added an edit description, I thought that was enough

Comment: I put the code back to where it was before the increment and typo were added.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't reopen the same file:

```
...
ofstream file ("numbers.txt");
file.open ("numbers.txt", ios::out | ios::app ); // Remove this line
int i = 0;
...
```

That will make it work. However, the program won't ever stop, since you forgot to increment `i` too!

Comment: `file.close();` is unnecessary for a similar reason.

Comment: Yeah, this worked, also I incremented "i"

Comment: @bitmask In general, it is best to call explicitly close operations. In particular if they can fail. But yeah, in this particular case, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: I disagree. What is "best" is to consistently use RAII and correctly scoped objects.

Comment: RAII is not meant to handle potentially failing operations. Silently ignoring errors is definitely *not* a best practice. Closing a file is the prime example of something that can fail in many ways and thus cannot be properly modeled in a C++ destructor.

Answer (score 1):

As said by other users in comments, you have an infinite loop: incrementing your loop control variable solves this problem. Then is not necessary to open and close the file explicitly if you use the standard library.

I would add that generally speaking rand() is not the function you may want to use, because it generates pseudo-random numbers, and even if it is ok for your application you may want to give a seed to it, throught the function [srand()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/srand/).

If you want more from you program, have a look a [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random) reference page.